# showing interface dependencies in UML

Tags: interface, dependencies, uml

Say I have the following interface and class

[image: UML Interface and implementing class]

This has a association dependency on SomeObject like so
[image: UML Interface, implementing class and associated class]

Does the interface, IDoSomething, have a dependency on SomeClass? Should I show this in UML?

Clearly the interface does have a dependency but this looks like noise to me:

[image: UML Interface, implementing class and associated class, showing dependency from Interface to associated class]

I was thinking that you could infer the interfaces dependency from DoSomethingImpl's dependencies, but this wouldn't work if it implemented multiple interfaces.

If the interface implemented another interface then I would expect that dependancy to be shown, but I'm worried about my UML becoming unnecessarily complex.

What would be a suitable thing to do?

Comment: The tool you are using draws wrong arrow heads. I assume it's something from Mickeysoft (notorious for doing anything their way),

Comment: @ThomasKilian Can you elaborate? I'm using [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/class-diagram#Relations), so its possible I've selected the wrong arrows.

Comment: The way connectors are drawn is crucial (and the most difficult part in UML). I couldn't find a summary on the fly, but http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html shows a coupe of examples (especially how arrowheads from above should look like). Obviously the tool is implemented wrongly.

Comment: So are you suggesting I should show a more specific form of dependency, like association? (Selecting the correct relationship is an area I struggle with sometimes)

Comment: No. Basically your drawing is correct. Just the tool does not show the correct form (probably because the creators thought that arrows should be more "artistic" which in this case is plain wrong).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have used to show dependency is fully correct. It's not a noise since you can't derive this information from other relationships. On the other hand you don't have to show a dependency, especially that this relationship is obvious (you have this class referred in both parameter and result of operation).

If you insist on explicit showing the dependency but you're afraid it'll decrease clarity of diagram rather than increasing it, you can put it on a separate diagram.

I would create a dependency for traceability purposes (only if your tool supports it) but hide it on diagrams.

Comment: Generally I agree. But not with _you don't have to show a dependency_. Though a dependency is a weak relation, it's nevertheless important. Leaving it away will present an imprecise picture to the reader. So if not shown on a specific (main) diagram, it shall appear on a (detail) diagram elsewhere.

Comment: Technically the existence of the dependency in the model can be implied, as I wrote in my answer, so the modl will be complete. Besides you don't have to show every aspect of the system in the model (however obviously this aspect is important). I agree that it is a good practice to show this dependency also visually (as a Dependency arrow) but it is not mandatory. So you *don't have to*, but it is *strongly advisable* to show it either on this particular diagram or somewhere else explicitly.

Comment: That was a late reply ;-) but in general I agree.