# showing abstract class dependencies in UML

Tags: dependencies, uml, abstract

If I have the following model
[image: UML 1]

Would it be acceptable to reduce this to the following?
[image: UML 2]
My logic would be: `SomeClassA` and `SomeClassB` inherit `BaseSomeClass` (and it's dependencies) therefore we can deduce `SomeClassA` and `SomeClassB` will depend on `SomeObject`.

Is this (my final UML) technically correct? 
Is it reasonable (Whether or not technically correct)?
Would it be different if `DoSomething` on `BaseSomeClass` was an abstract method?

I have a feeling the answer will be similar to my question on [showing interface dependencies in UML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419698/showing-interface-dependencies-in-uml) but I feel this is different enough to merit its own question.

Comment: I don't think, that this edit is an improvement. The dependency was just right. An association means that you have an attribute of that type. But you just use it in an operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance means, that you make some kind of "abstract clone". In other words, it has not only the general class' attributes/operations, but also its dependencies. In that way your second diagram is preferred. The first is not wrong, but the two dependencies from the specialized classes are already present and must not be repeated.

To cite Einstein: Everything Should Be Made as Simple as Possible, But Not Simpler

Answer (score -1):

For me your second diagram with one dependency only is the good one.

Looking at your diagram, I have some questions:
- why do you want to show dependencies so precisely ? As already commented on your other question, that's possible, that's make sense but, for me, in most of UML class diagram all dependencies are not shown (even if they are modeled).

- your method as a parameter of type SomeObject and return a SomeObject, does your class gets an attribute of type SomeObject. If this is the case, the relation is an association instead of a dependency.

Comment: Yes you are right they should be association not dependency, I should probably update the images

Comment: I guess I'm torn between using what is useful, in my current circumstance (which is more documenting and explaining rather than design) and understanding what is 'right' in UML, so I don't take 'bad' (or perhaps inappropriate) habits to my future work

Comment: Just leave it with the first sentence and don't answer with a question. Place it in a comment of the question instead.

Comment: I corrected the images to be association not dependency

Comment: _the relation is an association instead of a dependency_ is wrong. There is no attribute. `SomeObject` is only used as parameter/result of an operation. That's not an attribute!